# Dynamic projection in linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following dictionary of strings:

```
FirstName | Col1
LastName  | Col2
Email     | Col3
```

My database table looks like this (Crazy, I know):

```
Id   Col1   Col2    Col3
1    John   Doe     test@email.com
```

Now, I need to select a list of values in my c# code with aliases. It would be easy to do this with projection, like so (This would solve this task for me only if I could hardcode Property names and column names):

```
ctx.myTable.Select(x=> new { FirstName = x.Col1, LastName = x.Col2, Email = x.Col3});
```

But unfortunatelly I only have column names and alises stored as strings in a dictionary.  Looks like this is the job for expression trees or dynamic sql but I couldn't figure out how to achieve this. I tried to do it with Expando object but in return I'm getting a dictionary, while I need to have a list with columns FirstName, LastName, Email.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what you are hoping to achieve. Even if you manage to build the object at runtime you will only be able to work against it via reflection, because at compile time you won't know what it looks like. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @briantyler, you are probably correct. What I need to do is to dump this data into excel. I already have a method that does this automatically by using properties as headers. But maybe a different approach with datatable would be better. I'm using epplus

Comment: Yeah, read the table it into a `DataTable`, rename the columns and then dump it into Excel. I wouldn't over engineer it.

Comment: @briantyler, thanks for the suggestion Brian

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically construct SQL query as simple string:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["FirstName"] = "Col1",
    ["LastName"] = "Col2",
    ["Email"] = "Col3"
};

var query = $"select {String.Join(", ", dict.Select(x => $"{x.Value} as {x.Key}"))} from myTable";

var items = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<object>(query).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Slava, this looks exactly what I need. Will test later today